# Problems uploading JPEG to Parse in swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, jpeg

I'm having trouble getting my JPEG image to appear on Parse after succesfully saving it. Here is my code:

```
var createPost = PFObject(className: "Loading_Post")

createPost["userObjectId"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId

let imageOne = image1.image as UIImage!
let imageData1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageOne, 0.5)
let imageFile1 = PFFile(name: "image1.jpg", data: imageData1!)

print(imageFile1)

createPost["image1"] = imageFile1

createPost.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        self.displayAlert("success! ", message: "Your Post has been saved successfully")
    } else {
        self.displayAlert("Could not post image", message: "Please try again later")
    }
}
```

The code runs and everything is correctly stored in Parse except for the image which remains "undefined", yet my print statement returns:

> `<PFFile: 0x7fed357c8580>`

Thanks!

Comment: May be you need to save the `PFFile` for image first and then save to `PFObject`. Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18840159/1434338)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you need to save the `PFFile` for image first and then save it to `PFObject`. Try this,

```
imageFile1.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in

  if error == nil {

     var createPost = PFObject(className: "Loading_Post")

     createPost["userObjectId"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId

     createPost["image1"] = imageFile1

     createPost.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            self.displayAlert("success! ", message: "Your Post has been saved successfully")

        } else {

            self.displayAlert("Could not post image", message: "Please try again later")
        }

  } else {

     self.displayAlert("Could not post image", message: "Please try again later")
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple spelling mistake when trying to save to parse. "image1" should have been "Image1". Sorry for not catching this earlier!