# How can I add custom fields to my parse sign up view controller on swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfuser

Could you guys help? Im trying to add couple custom fields to my sign up form but I don't really know how to. I would like to add a company, name, phone, address and website field.

this is my code on my signUpViewController

thanks heaps

```
import UIKit
```

import Parse

class CreateAccountViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var dialogView: DesignableView!
@IBOutlet weak var messageLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var namesField: DesignableTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var usernameField: DesignableTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var companyField: DesignableTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: DesignableTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var phoneNumberField: DesignableTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailField: DesignableTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var office: DesignableTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var websiteField: DesignableTextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}



@IBAction func closeButtonDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    dialogView.animation = "fall"
    dialogView.animate()
}

@IBAction func signupButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    var username = self.usernameField.text
    var name = self.namesField.text
    var password = self.passwordField.text
    var email = self.emailField.text
    var phone = self.phoneNumberField.text
    var company = self.companyField.text
    var office = self.office.text
    var website = self.websiteField.text


    // Validate the text fields
    if username!.characters.count < 5 {
        var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Invalid", message: "You need to use your LBP number", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()

    } else if password!.characters.count < 8 {
        var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Try again", message: "Password must be longer than 8 characters", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()

    } else if email!.characters.count < 8 {
        var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Try again", message: "Please enter a valid email address", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()

    } else {


        // Run a spinner to show a task in progress
        var spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150)) as UIActivityIndicatorView
        spinner.startAnimating()

        var newUser = PFUser()

        newUser.username = username
        newUser.password = password
        newUser.email = email

        // Sign up the user asynchronously
        newUser.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succeed, error) -> Void in

            // Stop the spinner
            spinner.stopAnimating()
            if ((error) != nil) {
                var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Error", message: "\(error)", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alert.show()

            } else {
                var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Success", message: "You've been signed up to Build Cert", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alert.show()
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home") as! UIViewController
                    self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                })
            }
        })
    }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the *set object for key* method. As an example:

```
newUser.setObject(self.office.text, forKey:"office")
```

Comment: Thanks heaps mate! It worked perfectly - now another quick question and I'll be done with my project - how could I add a picture, so basically get the user to upload a profile pic from his phone. Thanks again!

Comment: @EugenioCubyMercado you're welcome! You can use 'imagePickerController' to do this. Once they take the picture, here's a good thread that has two answers outlining how to upload. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839834/how-to-upload-an-image-to-parse-com-from-uiimageview. If you get a chance, I would really appreciate it if you could mark this answer as accepted if you're satisfied. Thank you.