# Trying to upload image from iOS to parse.com

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to upload an image from an iOS app to a Parse class.

The ViewController has two buttons and an ImageView

**Button 1** : Select picture from device's PhotoGallery,

**ImageView** (myImageView): shows the selected picture.

This part of the app is working fine.

In Parse, I have created a class called **citas_servicio**, with a column called **foto**, from type file.

Button 2 action is **subirFoto**:

```
@IBAction func subirFoto(sender: AnyObject) {
    if myImageView.image == nil {
        //image is not included alert user
        print("Image not uploaded")
     }else {
         var posts = PFObject(className: "citas_servicio")
         posts.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({(success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
             if error == nil {
                 /**success saving, Now save image.***/

                 //create an image data
                 var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.myImageView.image!)
                 //create a parse file to store in cloud
                 var parseImageFile = PFFile(name: "uploaded_image.png", data: imageData!)
                 posts["foto"] = parseImageFile
                 posts.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                     if error == nil {
                         //take user home
                         print("data uploaded")
                     }else {
                         print(error)
                     }
                 })
             }else {
                 print(error)
             }
         })
     }
 }
```

Once `Button2` is clicked, a new record is created in Parse, but the Image is not added in it, and no message is printed in the console.

What is wrong in the code?

Comment: please refer following link :- http://stackoverflow.com/a/18840159/5247310

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saving `Object` before setting `foto` in posts thats why you are getting error. First save image then set it to `Object`:

```
let posts = PFObject(className: "citas_servicio")
        //create an image data
        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.myImageView.image!)
        //create a parse file to store in cloud
        let parseImageFile = PFFile(name: "uploaded_image.png", data: imageData!)
        parseImageFile?.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in
            if success{
                posts["foto"] = parseImageFile
                posts.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        //take user home
                        print("data uploaded")
                    }else {
                        print(error)
                    }
                })
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

First save parseImageFile in background when success then associate it with PFObject and save posts(PFObject) in background.I hope it will work.

Comment: Thank you, but could you post your answer with a code example?

Comment: please refer following link :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839834/how-to-upload-an-image-to-parse-com-from-uiimageview/18840159#18840159

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to save the object, then save with photo again, just add to the `PFObject` after create it.

```
var posts = PFObject(className: "citas_servicio")
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.myImageView.image!)
let parseImageFile = PFFile(name: "uploaded_image.png", data: imageData!)
posts["foto"] = parseImageFile
```

After that, you can easily save the object in the background.